# Apply further configuration to Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder before it is used

Tags: spring-boot

SpringBoot comes with its own pre-configured `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` that is used through the framework to configure the various `ObjectMapper`.

The builder doesn't expose all facets of the `ObjectMapper` and I was wondering how I could apply additional configuration to the builder before it is used?

I can obviously provide my own `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` instance but then I would loose the default initialisation provided by SpringBoot...

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Create beans that extend com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule,
there you configure for example your own seriealizers and deserializers.

In the newer spring versions (dont know since when  but at least since spring 4 ) these beans are picked up automatically.

In older versions of spring you may need to add the Modules manually to the ObjectMapper, which is tricky, because spring creates many beans of type ObjetMapper and its not easy to find the right one.